# Replace multiple different nodes in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to efficiently (i.e. in a single pass) replace multiple nodes in an XML tree.

```
foreach (Object x in xmlTree.Nodes())
{
    XElement e = x as XElement;
    if (e != null)
    {
        switch (e.Name.LocalName)
        {
            case "a":
                e.ReplaceWith(new XElement("red", (string)e));
                break;
            case "b":
                e.ReplaceWith(new XElement("blue", (string)e));
                break;
            // And a few other mappings...
        }
    }
}
```

I think the above code invalidates the iterator after the first replace.

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`.

Comment: How many levels does your xml have?